# Dead Island Riptide character keeps glitching into ground?

Tags: xbox-360, dead-island-riptide

Whenever I play Dead Island Riptide the Chapter 1 mission tells me that I have to go and defend the camp.

However, every time I try to cross the bridge the game lags and I go straight through the bridge and I get stuck halfway into the ground. I can't move or turn but the zombies can still hurt me. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: **NEVERMIND !!** I found a solution. If anyone experiences this problem then try and kill the zombies before they get fully over the bridge because one of them (in this case ) glitches into the side of the bridge and that's what causes you to go down.